# MVC4 Web API remove validation, throwing 400 bad request

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-web-api, requiredfieldvalidator

I am using MVC4 Razor engine.

I have model with Required attribute. But in my case, in edit mode, I need to remove that validation.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegEmail , new { @class = "inp-form",data_val = false})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegEmail)
```

I have done for textbox control but how to remove modelstate required attribute for webapi , as it throwing 400 bad request and showing that field is required.

Anyone know how to remove validation from webapi as throwing 400 bad request?

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute `[ValidateInput(false)]` on either the (action) method level or the controller level. It should disable all input validation.